# Magento2: Add external JS globally

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to add external js in my module which will be applicable on all pages on frontend. This is the process I've followed:
1. Code in my layout file `app/code/Lapisbard/General/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="frontend-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Lapisbard_General::js/ro_allpage.js"/>
    </head>
    <body/>
</page>
```

2. Added js file at `app/code/Lapisbard/General/view/frontend/web/js/ro_allpage.js` with following code

```
define('js/theme', [
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('Hello');
});
```

I see my file is being added on the page but it throws console error **Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined**. What I'm doing wrong?
Also I tried code below which throws **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

```
require(["jquery"], function($){
    console.log("hello");
});
```

Comment: why not you use requirejs-config.js to add custom js

Comment: @ShaheerAli: Can you share an example how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place requirejs-config.js in the view/frontend folder of your module. Requirejs-config.js looks like:

```
 var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        mycustomjs:           'Vendor_Module/js/mycustomjs',

    }
}};
```

and now Then in your phtml file

```
  require(['jquery', 'mycustomjs'], function($,mycustomjs){
      $(function(){
         // Custom code here
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code is working in phtml files. but same code is not working properly in my js file `ro_allpage.js` . It gives same error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` though prints output `hello` in console.

Comment: can you post errors here?

Comment: `require(['jquery', 'mycustomjs'], function($, mycustomjs){
    $(function(){
        console.log("hello");
    });
});` prints `hello` in console but gives error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: you still including your js through head? did you flush out your magento cache?

Comment: require-config.js code is `var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            mycustomjs: 'Lapisbard_General/js/ro_allpage',

        }
    }};` .Yes I've includedjs through head in layout's default.xml `<head>
        <link src="Lapisbard_General::js/ro_allpage.js"/>
    </head>`

Comment: you have no need to add your js in layout head. require-config.js automatically add it for you. also clear you cache and remove pub/static/frontend folder

Comment: I've cleared cache. I've included ro_allpage.js though head not require-config.js .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34585/discussion-between-shaheer-ali-and-amitshree).

Comment: see my updated comment you have no need to add your js through head. Require js is do ths for you

Comment: inserting javascript code in phtml files is not good practice, especially if it is a large piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I add dotdotdot library in my magento2 custom theme.

**1. Download and add Js Library in your theme following the path:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js
```

**2. Create a theme's requirejs file as follow and let the requirejs know newly added library.**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           dotdotdot: 'js/jquery.dotdotdot.min',
       }
   }
};
```

**3. Use the added library in your theme's main js file as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/main.js
require([ 'jquery' , 'dotdotdot' , 'domReady!'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        //custom js code
        /* $(".product-item-name").each(function(){
            $(this).dotdotdot(); 
        }); */
    });
});
```

**4. and include your theme's js file in your site's head as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/main.js"/> 
    </head>
</page>
```

You can add any external JS library and custom file on every page in magento2.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using the script method rather than the text method, it's easier for other developers to understand, it's less code, and meets Magento's official instructions.

To do this use the same script or link XML as normal but include `src_type="url"`. Check this out official Doc [URL](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css).

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" />

</head></page>
```