# I need to add masonry js to my theme in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery

Im unable to successfully get masonry working for my Magento 2.0 theme. What i have done currently is i added the link to Masonry cdn to my file default_head_blocks.xml and also called the function from one of my CMS pages. But no luck, nothing works.

Here is my default_head_blocks.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />
        <link src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300" src_type="url" /> 
        <link src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js" src_type="url" />         
    </head>
</page>
```

Here is CMS page content

```
    <div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Grid 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"> Grid 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Grid 3</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){

    var $container = $('. grid');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.grid-item'
      });
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: for jquery follow this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97184/how-to-use-jquery-library-in-magento-2

Comment: @QaisarSatti thanks for the response but how do i properly include masonry js in my file?

Comment: remove the code from cms page that is causing the problem. you are adding the file correctly `<head><link src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js" src_type="url" />         
    </head>` for external js follow this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98091/magento2-add-external-js-globally

Answer (score 7):

Do not include JavaScript files in Magento 2 layout XML!

I'm using masonry on my M2 project, and want to share it with you.

To use `masonry.js` in Magento 2 add this piece of code to your template file (copy from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/product/list.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Namespace/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`):

```
<script>
// require the require function
requirejs( [ 'require', 'jquery', 'path/to/masonry.pkgd.js' ],
  function( require, $, Masonry ) {
    // require jquery-bridget, it's included in masonry.pkgd.js
    require( [ 'jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget' ],
    function( jQueryBridget ) {
      // make Masonry a jQuery plugin
      jQueryBridget( 'masonry', Masonry, $ );
      // now you can use $().masonry()
      $('.grid').masonry({...});
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

You need to use such construction to [run masonry as jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html#requirejs)
In my case it's look like this:

```
<script>
requirejs( [ 'require', 'jquery', 'Magefan_Blog/js/lib/masonry.pkgd.min' ],
function( require, $, Masonry ) {
    require( [ 'jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget' ],
    function( jQueryBridget ) {
        jQueryBridget( 'masonry', Masonry, $ );
        $('.post-list').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post-holder',
            percentPosition: true
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

The source code you can find on [github](https://github.com/magefan/module-blog/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/widget/recent_masonry.phtml).

[masonry.pkgd.min.js](https://github.com/magefan/module-blog/blob/master/view/frontend/web/js/lib/masonry.pkgd.min.js) I have put to:

```
vendor/magefan/module-blog/view/frontend/web/js/lib/masonry.pkgd.min.js
```

Hope this helps someone.

If anybody have better suggestion, please let to know.

Comment: Which M2 version was in use when you wrote this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `require-js` to load masonry. [On the website](http://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html#requirejs) it is stated how it works. For Magento2:

1. load the `masonry.js` into your themes `web/js`-folder.
2. Register in require-js:

   ```
   var config = {

   map: {
       '*': {
           'masonry' : 'js/masonry'
       }
   },
   "shim": {
       "masonry": ['jquery', 'jquery/ui'],
   }
   };
   ```
3. put the code in your `list.phtml`

   ```
   requirejs( [ 'require', 'jquery', 'masonry' ],
   function( require, $, Masonry ) {
   // require jquery-bridget, it's included in masonry.pkgd.js
        require( [ 'jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget' ],
           function( jQueryBridget ) {
            // make Masonry a jQuery plugin
            jQueryBridget( 'masonry', Masonry, $ );
            // now you can use $().masonry()
            $('.grid').masonry({ 
              // your settings 
           });
         }
       );
     });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use script tag to include your external js in layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    .......
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js" src_type="url" />         
</head>
```