# Magento 2: get masonry working / source file path

Tags: magento2, requirejs

- **Magento2** is installed **via composer**
- I've written a custom theme, based on luma
- masonry is installed via bower - the bower_components folder is placed in: app/design/frontend/VENDOR/MY_THEME/web

I've defined a new requireJS module for masonry in a requirejs-config.js

**Question 1:** Where should that file be? In .../MY_THEME/Magento_Theme or directly in my theme?
**Question 2:** What is the correct path to the masonry source file in the bower_components? Because all my custom js-files end up somewhere below pub/static/frontend...

```
var config = {
    paths:{
        // creates a module named 'masonry'
        // points to the masonry source file
        "masonry":"???/web/bower_components/masonry/masonry"
    },

    shim:{
        // make sure that jquery is completely loaded when masonry starts loading
        'masonry':{
            'deps':['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

I've read the answers of [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98936/i-need-to-add-masonry-js-to-my-theme-in-magento-2) question - but can't get it work without the correct source path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question1**

Directly in your theme. Your `requirejs-config.js` will be:

```
var config = {
    map:{
        "masonry":"bower_components/masonry/masonry"
    },
    shim:{
       'masonry':{
            'deps':['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

**Question2**

The correct path could be `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/web/js/bower_components` if you use your dependency directly. During the static asset deployment Magento will put you resources in `pub/static/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/LOCALE/js/bower_components`.

Comment: Thank you, I already found that out :-) It works for me with this path in map: 
"web/bower_components/masonry/masonry"