# Layout Update XML doesn't properly work for the home page

Tags: magento2, xml

I'm using magento 2 and I'm trying to add this code into my Layout Update XML.

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type><script>jsfilename.js</script>
  </action>
</reference>
```

But for some reason, my js doesn't get loaded on the home page.

what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Is your js present under `skin/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/jsfilename.js` ?

Comment: @alexcr make sure are you using magento-1 or magento-2? magento-2 doesn't have skin folder

Comment: you mean app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/jsfilename.js ? Yes it is ! and yes I'm using magento 2

Answer (score 1):

I would not advise adding the JS via the XML anymore, Magento 2 best practices are to use Require JS.

Please see the official docs [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html) and [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html) - or my answer to a related question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114248/magento-2-add-jquery-on-specific-page/114400#114400)

Require JS can be added via the template files with data-mage-init attributes (on the element to trigger the script) or a script tag (define the element to trigger the script).

```
<nav data-mage-init='{ "<component_name>": {...} }'></nav>

<!-- Or with the script tag -->


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#test": {
            "Magento_Cms/js/your-script-name-here": {
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 The format will change
Please refer to below URL to add custom js in a head.

[Add custom js in head in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86243/add-custom-js-in-head-in-magento2)

Answer (score 0):

Using below code you can add css and js:

Create cms_index_index.xml to add css and js only for homepage at **app/code/Namesapce/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">        
            <head>        
                 <css src="Namespace_Modulename::css/filename.css"/>    
                 <script type="text/javascript"  src="Namespace_Modulename::js/filename.js"/>   
            </head>        
    </page>
```

Add css file at **app/code/Namesapce/Modulename/view/frontend/web/css/filename.css**

Add js file at **app/code/Namesapce/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/filename.js**

Comment: yes but this is gonna insert me the js only for the home page ? or every page ? cause I only need it on the home page..

Comment: This will added to all page change default.xml file name to cms_index_index.xml it's only add to homepage

Comment: I don't think <head> should be inside <body>, just <head> is enough.

Comment: Yes right i have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add only inside homepage using below code,

```
app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml
```

`cms_index_index.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>        
       <css src="Vendor_Modulename::css/styles.css"/>    
       <script src="Vendor_Modulename::js/custom.js"/>   
    </head>>
    <body>
       //body code
    </body>
</page>
```

Put css file at **app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/css/styles.css**

Put js file at **app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js**

Comment: Have you heard of `Layout Update XML`

Comment: @StevieG, why have you downvote, please reason me.

Comment: You are using custom code, the question is asking how to make the layout update via the `admin` section

Comment: @StevieG, but you have to inform user not do like down vote, Its usedful to many user using xml code