# Adding Instafeed on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want to add `Instafeed.js` on my Magento 2 theme. How to write correct JS?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the javascript SDK of an instagram plugin, not about Magento specific code

Comment: Hi @SanderMangel i'm not developer, so i wanna know how to code js for magento.

Comment: I feel your comment is very broad and you're not aware of the docs, they do a very good job of explaining how to add your own JS. I recommend using Require JS which is built in to Magento 2 - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Comment: Hi @Ben-Space48 thank you for replay. but it won't help me. i've already try my best way. i'm just Photoshop and CSS guy. it will be great help and thanks if you provide me proper code.

Comment: There are already questions for this, I have answered one here - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114248/magento-2-add-jquery-on-specific-page/114400#114400