# magento 2 module's css and js files include

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created a basic plugin in magento 2 and also included **.css** file in correct place as I have seen in many tutorials but when I open frontend page of magento 2(luma page) and do page inspect and in the console after open the issue in tab , it shows :- `Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Excellence_Hello/css/style.css'`

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\StaticResource.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\pub\static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
#3 {main}
```

what to do to ??? I am also sharing my extension on's [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B14xx1stWvMOZzhTMmczdXdETjQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong directory path in your layout file. You keep css and js both in `view/frontend/web` but in your layout file you mentioned `view/frontend/web/css` and `view/frontend/web/js` so it will throw above error

in your layout file change source path like below

```
<css src="Excellence_Hello::style.css"/>
<script src="Excellence_Hello::style.js"/>
```

**opinion:** This is not a good practice to add js. refer this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98091/magento2-add-external-js-globally) to add js

Comment: thank u so much....